# Press a shortcut again to undo the action?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

For example, to open the context menu for a highlighted item in Nautilus, one can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open the context menu (cf. [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167088/keyboard-shortcut-equivalent-to-right-clicking)). However, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> again does not close the menu, as I would have expected.

Is there a way to enable this behaviour for this shortcut (and for other similar shortcuts, in general)? Alternatively, is there another keyboard action I can use to close the context menu (I don't want to click the mouse)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may press <kbd>esc</kbd> to close the context menu.